# "guter gesundheitlicher Versorgung" why 'er'?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case, adjective, adjective-ending

> „Viele Menschen genießen dank finanzieller Absicherung durch das Rentensystem und guter gesundheitlicher Versorgung ihr Rentnerdasein.“

In this sentence I cannot understand why adjectives - 'guter' and' gesundheitlicher' have er in the end even though nouns are feminine and in nominative case. Same goes with " finanzieller Absicherung" again feminine noun in nominative but er in the end. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

You're missing the preposition "**[dank](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dank)**" which requires Genitive (or Dative, i personally prefer Genitive). Thus, "Gesundheitsversorgung" / "Versorgung" isn't Nominative but Genitive, indicated by the adjectives "guter" and "gesundheitlicher" (both *Genitive*, [strong inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension#Strong_inflection)).

The strong inflection makes it quite hard to recognize the Genitive case. With weak inflection, it would be easier, i think:

> viele Menschen genießen dank **der** finanzielle**n** Absicherung durch das Rentensystem und **der** gute**n** gesundheitliche**n** Versorgung ihr Rentnerdasein...